# How to solve "Exception thrown: write access violation."

Tags: c++, access-violation

I'm writing a simple program which is expected to create a linked list, then take inputs as names and GPAs for each student.

```
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

struct studentList {
    struct student* student;
    struct studentList* next;
}*list = NULL;

struct student {
    char* name;
    double gpa;
};

int main() {
    studentList* headPointer = NULL;            //create a head pointer to the list
    studentList* tailPointer = NULL;            //create a tail pointer to the list
    studentList* displayPointer = NULL;
    studentList* stuListPtr = NULL;
    student* stuPtr = NULL;
    char choice;
    double gpa;
    char* tempName = NULL;
    int count = 0;
while (1) {
    cout << "1. Add student record\n";
    cout << "2. Display student records\n";
    cout << "3. Count number of records\n";
    cout << "4. Exit\n";
    cin >> choice;
    switch (choice) {
    case '1':
        count++;
        stuListPtr = (studentList*)( malloc(count * sizeof(studentList)));
        stuPtr = (student*)(malloc(count * sizeof(student)));
        cout << "What is the name of the student?\n";
        cin >> tempName;
        stuListPtr->student->name = tempName;
        cout << "What is his/her GPA?\n";
        cin >> stuListPtr->student->gpa;
        if (headPointer == NULL) {
            headPointer = stuListPtr;
            tailPointer = stuListPtr;
        }
        else if (headPointer != NULL) {
            tailPointer->next = stuListPtr;//memory of the SL type
        }
        stuListPtr->next;
        break;
```

After I input '1' as choice to choose case 1, the program asks me for a name, after giving the name, the program ends automatically. I tried to put a breakpoint at the line where it takes the name as tempName, the error "Exception thrown: write access violation" popped up. Can anyone please help me with this?

P.S.
A green underline under the `stuListPtr->student->name = tempName;`, and says "Dereferencing NULL pointer 'stuListPtr'"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Segmentation fault when using stream extraction into a char pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329294/segmentation-fault-when-using-stream-extraction-into-a-char-pointer/2329323#2329323)

Comment: You allocate `stuListPtr` and also `stuPtr`, but you attempt to assign the input to `stuListPtr->student`, which is not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

welcome on SO, you allocated your pointer but you didn't initialize it. For this reason this line fails :

```
stuListPtr->student->name = tempName;
```

Because `stuListPtr` points to a place allocated but without data in it.